# jQuery to redirect page to URL that serves as reverse proxy to the page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, http, redirect, unbounce

Let's say there's a domain, xyz.com, registered and managed at DNSSimple. A Rails application is configured to serve a website at https://www.xyzDOTcom. There's also a sub-domain, https://get.xyzDOTcom that is configured to serve several landing pages set up using [Unbounce](https://unbounce.com/).

Now, the SEO guy wants all the Unbounce pages to be made accessible via https://www.xyzDOTcom/storage/PAGE. I implemented this by adding Rack's reverse-proxy to the config.ru.

**Problem** - The SEO guy also wants the existing https://get.xyzDOTcom/PAGE URLs to redirect (301) to their corresponding https://www.xyzDOTcom/storage/PAGE counterparts. Unbounce allows embedding custom Javascript blogs to its pages, so I tried `window.location = , window.location.replace(), window.location.href =` etc, but they all resulted in an infinite redirect loop when trying to access https://get.xyzDOTcom/PAGE.

How do I achieve this 301 redirect of https://get.xyzDOTcom/PAGE to the corresponding reverse-proxy https://www.xyzDOTcom/storage/PAGE?

Answer (score 0):

How about

- Create a new subdomain `get2.xyzDOTcom`
- Configure Unbounce to use `get2.xyzDOTcom` instead of `get.xyzDOTcom`
- Configure your Rails app to reverse proxy to `get2.xyzDOTcom`
- Setup a new web server for `get.xyzDOTcom`
- Let the new web server redirect (301) to `www.xyzDOTcom`

Note: If the whole exercise is because of SEO, it might be a bad idea to do a JavaScript redirect anyway.

Note 2: Don't know if that is an option for you, but [Cloudflare Page Rules](https://www.cloudflare.com/features-page-rules/) would make this a no-brainer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, as per Chris Searles' answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846738/are-301-redirects-possible-using-javascript-or-jquery, JS redirects seem to do the job from the SEO standpoint as well?