# 301 redirect on next static export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm currently working on a Next.js project, and I have used static export to improve performance and SEO. However, I've encountered an issue related to URL changes. I'd like to implement **301 redirect**. so that search engines and users are redirected to the updated pages.

Any help, code snippets, or pointers to the right documentation would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried redirects in next.config.js and getServerSideProps but these methods are not supported in static export.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.pathname` to set the path of the current url. Just place this code on the page you want to redirect from.

```js
export default function Page() {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        window.location.pathname = "replacement_url"; 
    }

    return (
        ...
    );
}
```

I wrapped it in an `if` statement because React throws the following error when you try to use `window`.

```
    ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

MDN has some `window.location` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)

Comment: middleware is also not supported in static export.
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports#unsupported-features

Comment: @amanpandey oh you're right. It also says that redirects are unsupported. Is switching to the AppRouter an option? Although middleware is unsupported for static exports in the AppRouter as well, but is only seems to mention redirects for static exports being unsupported in `nextjs.config.js`

Comment: @amanpandey I think I found a solution and I updated my answer. Let me know if it works

Comment: this is not 301 redirection. it will redirect the URL on the client side.

Comment: @amanpandey you're right, again. A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13846738/17443354) has been asked before though, and [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13846778/17443354), and I'm not sure that there is a work around for `static exports` if you need a server for `301  redirects`